# How can I change timer picker to spinner

Tags: android, timepicker

Here, the time picker is show in this mode. I want to change to spinner mode how can I change to spinner mode.

```
     val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
            val date = sdf.parse(pickUpTime)
            val picker = TimePickerDialog(
                this, R.style.DatePickerTheme,
                { tp, sHour, sMinute ->
                    handleTimeValidity(sHour, sMinute)
                },
                date?.hours ?: 12,
                date?.minutes ?: 12,
                true
            )

            picker.show()
```

```
    <style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
        <item name="android:format24Hour">false</item>
        <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the style I can change timerPickerMode to spinner but it is not visible as spinner

This is my current result[image]
[image: This is my current result]

Comment: Try checking out this medium article: https://medium.com/@yottafactory/android-timepicker-timepicker-dialog-spinner-clock-mode-b92ad4c4cb5c

Answer (score 1):

To change the `TimePickerDialog` to `spinner` mode instead of `clock` you should define the `android:timePickerStyle` in your `DatePickerTheme` like the below example:

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/MyTimePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

The `MyTimePickerStyle` is a custom `TimePickerStyle` which extends from `@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker` where you can define the `android:timePickerMode` there.

In case also you want to render the `spinner` mode in AM/PM you have to set the `is24HourView` parameter to false in the `TimePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)` constructor like the below example:

```
val picker = TimePickerDialog(this, R.style.DatePickerTheme, { tp, sHour, sMinute ->

    }, 12, 12, false
)
picker.show()
```

**Result:**

[image: time_picker_spinner_mode]

Comment: val picker = TimePickerDialog(
                this, R.style.MyTimePickerStyle,
                { tp, sHour, sMinute ->
                    handleTimeValidity(sHour, sMinute)
                },
                date?.hours ?: 12,
                date?.minutes ?: 12,
                false
            )
            picker.show()

Comment: I have tired but cannot get spinner mode

Comment: @Aashis you are using `TimePickerDialog(this, R.style.MyTimePickerStyle` which is wrong change it to `TimePickerDialog(this, R.style.DatePickerTheme` like in my answer check it carefully.